# jquery: array from php ever undefined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm not many experience with javascript so I can't find a solution for my problem
Below I pasted the php code and javascript code! Javascript call php for select and update all row wih recd field 0 every 6 secs ... It works because the db updating every 6 secs but, I can't use the items array in javascript because the alert sayd me that is undefined.... How can is possible????

Php page:

```
if ($_GET['action'] == "chatheartbeat") { chatHeartbeat(); } 

function chatHeartbeat() {  
global $mysqli;

$cuser="Guest"; 
$idchat=2;//Chat ID
$items=[];  

if ($idchat!=""){
    $sql = "select * from chat where idchat=".$idchat." and recd=0 order by id ASC";                
    $result=$mysqli->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows>0){           
        while($row=$result->fetch_array()){             
            $sqlup="UPDATE chat SET recd = '1' WHERE idchat = ".$row['idchat'];             
            if ($mysqli->query($sqlup)=== FALSE){
                echo "Error updating record" . $mysqli->error;
            }
            $items[$row['id']]['f']=$row['from'];
            $items[$row['id']]['m']=$row['message'];
        }
    }
}
//header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($items);
```

javascript file

```
function chatHeartbeat(){               
$.ajax({        
url: 'chat.php?action=chatheartbeat',
type: 'POST',
dataType: 'JSON', 
cache: false,
success: function(data) {       
    alert(data.f);
    /*$.each(response.items, function(item){            
        console.log(response);
        if(item){               
            $(".chatboxcontent").append('<div class=chatboxmessage><span class="chatboxmessagefrom">'+item.f+': </span><span class="chatboxmessagecontent">'+item.m+'</span></div>');
        }
    })*/;                   
}   
});
setTimeout('chatHeartbeat();',6000);
```

How can I read this array in javascript???  In console log I have this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Comment: Can you show response from API

Comment: What do you get if you `console.log(data)`

Comment: You seem to be using console.log, why not use console.log(data) to see what the data object is.  @Samurai beat me to it.

Comment: Maybe you need `JSON.parse(data)`

Comment: @Orifjon No need to parse as using `dataType: json`

Comment: maybe this work : echo json_encode($items , JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);

Comment: Note that you are also overwriting your results in the php loop. To avoid that, you can use something like `$items[$row['id']]["f"] = $row['from']; // etc`

Comment: @Samurai this is the console: `{"f":"Guest","m":"asdf"}`

Comment: @jeroen lol hai ragione.... The call is every 1 second but you right.. now I fix the code... thks

Comment: This is the response of console: `chat.js:58 
chat.js:58 {"1":{"f":"Guest","m":"asdasd"},"2":{"f":"Guest","m":"asdasdsad"},"3":{"f":"Guest","m":"dghgdgh"},"4":{"f":"Guest","m":"tsgfsgs"}}
4chat.js:58 `  .... I think that the php code works and the problem is in the recovery array.... why I have undefined and doesn't show the correct value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem

in php code I change the array with EOD

```
if ($idchat!=""){
    $sql = "select * from chat where idchat=".$idchat." and recd=0 order by id ASC";                
    $result=$mysqli->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows>0){           
        while($row=$result->fetch_array()){             
            $sqlup="UPDATE chat SET recd = '1' WHERE idchat = ".$row['idchat'];             
            if ($mysqli->query($sqlup)=== FALSE){
                echo "Error updating record" . $mysqli->error;
            }               
            $items.=<<<EOD
    {
"f": "{$row['from']}",
"m": "{$row['message']}"
},
EOD;
        }               
    }
}

header('Content-type: application/json');
?>
{
"items": [
        <?php echo $items;?>
    ]
}
```

In javascript code :

```
success: function(data) {                       
    $.each(data.items, function(i,item){            
        if(item){           
            console.log(item.f);
            $(".chatboxcontent").append('<div class=chatboxmessage><span class="chatboxmessagefrom">'+item.f+': </span><span class="chatboxmessagecontent">'+item.m+'</span></div>');
        }
    });                 
}
```